# URL rewriting via my .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

How do I change example.com/1 to example.com/?id=1

I've tried googling but I can only find code for example.com/?id=1 to example.com/1
I used a generator and got this, but it didn't work

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^\?get\=$ / [L]
```

Thanks, 
Isaac

Comment: Do you mean you want the user to go to "example.com/1" and it internally goes to "example.com/?id=1"?  Or the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of depends on which way you want to do the rewrite - ie, what does the user type see, and what does the server do.

If you want the user to see "http://example.com/1" and internally the server provides "http://example.com/?id=1", then the following should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /?id=$1
```

However, if you want the user see "http://example.com/?id=1", and internally the server provides "http://example.com/1", then the following, as per Jon Lin's answer, should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ /%1?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule` statement, you need to use a `RewriteCond` and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [L]
```

The `?` is needed in the rule's target to remove the query string.

Comment: @Isaac It does what you've asked for, when someone requests `example.com/?id=1`, it rewrites it to `example.com/1`. Now, if `example.com/1` doesn't exist, then of course you'll get a 404.

Comment: "How do I change example.com/1 to example.com/?id=1"